# Sufficient Condition for the convergence of Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I'm studying real analysis and I know about derivative, Riemann integral, sequence and series, basic concepts. I'm having trouble understanding the sufficient conditions for a Fourier series of a function converges to that function. Is the following statements true or false?

1. If the function $f$ is continuous and $2\pi$-periodic then the partial sum of the fourier series of $f$ converges pointwise to $f$ for every $x$.
2. If the function $f$ is continuous and $2\pi$-periodic with the derivative being absolutely (Riemann) integrable on $[0,2\pi]$ then the partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$
3. If the function $f$ is continuous and $2\pi$-periodic then $f$ and the fourier series satisfy the Parseval's identity:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|^2dx=\pi a_0^2+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\pi(a_i^2+b_i^2)$$

Comment: I just note here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions

Answer (score 1):

1. False. There exists example for continuous function but Fourier series diverges at some point.
2. Yes. It means $|f^{'}|$ is bounded, hence $f$ is Lipschitz on the circle ,we get uniform convergence.
3. Yes. Mean convergence ($L^2$ convergence) only requires integrability.

Comment: Can you give me some references about these? I would love to know when it's right to use fourier series, thanks!

Comment: @Mr. T For Q1, you can find an example in Fourier analysis textbook written by Stein, for Q2,3 see [this](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course/math3060/Chapter%201.%20Fourier%20series%20.pdf). In particular, theorem 1.7 and corollary 1.18.

Comment: In Q3, it must be $\frac 1 2 {\pi a_0^2}$

Comment: @HLong shouldn't it be $2\pi a_0^2$? I thought it's a typo.